# Custom implementation of Pageable

Tags: java, spring

I need to create custom implementation of a request with Paging to the database. I am able to fetch a list of all objects from database and manipulate this list.
This is how the PageableDto looks :

```
public class PageableDto {

    private Integer page;
    private Integer size;
}
```

This is how the function to return the paginated list of objects is implemented

```
private List<RequestDto> doPagination(PageableDto pageable, List<RequestDto> requests) {
        List<RequestDto> paginatedList = new ArrayList<>();
        Integer page = pageable.getPage();
        Integer size = pageable.getSize();
        if (page == 0 || page == 1) {
            for (int i = 0 ; i < size ; i++) {
                if (i < requests.size()) {
                    paginatedList.add(requests.get(i));
                } else {
                    return paginatedList;
                }
            }
            return paginatedList;
        }
        int startIndex = size * (page - 1);
        int endIndex = startIndex + size;
        for (int i = startIndex; i < endIndex ; i++) {
            if (i < requests.size()) {
                paginatedList.add(requests.get(i));
            } else {
                return paginatedList;
            }
        }
        return paginatedList;
    }
```

I am trying to make it work like the real Pageable Spring object, but the implementation is bad and I get unexpected results.

For example if the list is with 10 entries and **page** is 0 and **size** is 3  I will get the first three objects from the list. If **page** is 1 and **size** is 3 I will get entries 4,5,6 and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try with below code:

```
private List<RequestDto> doPagination(PageableDto pageable, List<RequestDto> requests) {
        List<RequestDto> paginatedList;
        Integer page = pageable.getPage();
        Integer size = pageable.getSize();
        int offset = page * size;
        if(requests.size()>offset){
            if(requests.size()>(offset+size)){
                paginatedList = requests.subList(offset, offset+size);
            }else{
                paginatedList = requests.subList(offset, requests.size());
            }
        }else{
            paginatedList = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        return paginatedList;
    }
```